# What does the grey dot in a box mean in GitHub GUI for Windows?

Tags: github-for-windows

Can somebody please explain to me what the grey dot in the box means for these files?  Clearly the + and - signs mean added and removed files, but I do not understand these boxes... I should also mention that these files are not empty. So I don't understand why it says "This file is empty".

[image]

Comment: I'd guess those are the files you want to "add" when you want to commit next time

Comment: On the command line, git status shows that there are no changes

Comment: My best guess would be something to do with line endings, but I have searched for an hour, and I can find no reference to this symbol

Comment: And I just noticed what the "gray dots" are, I was talking about the checkboxes, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I tried committing and pushing what I have, and there is nothing new to be added, so nothing happens.

Comment: Wow. That is the most unintuitive GUI I've seen in a while, and I've seen a lot of extremely unintuitive GUIs for Git. This "every application designs their own interface and controls" isn't helping usability on the Windows platform one bit. If I were to guess, I'd say that these are files that are "dirty", i.e. have uncommitted changes, but your investigation suggests that is not the case. Surely there's a help file that accompanies this application? Or did they spend too much time reinventing the UI wheel that they didn't have time to write docs?

Comment: Honestly I don't even know how to search for this... "github grey dot in a box"??? I have no idea what the heck this is... and hence no idea how to search for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this symbol indicates file permission changes. Some of the files were being generating on a Linux system, which assigned file permissions. However, when checking out the files, for some reason the permissions were changed. I have no idea why, but that is not the point.

In any case, permissions changes were not being shown by

```
git status
```

on the command line, but they WERE being shown in the GUI as the boxes above (although there is no comment anywhere indicating it). I verified the problem by opening a Cygwin console and calling

```
ls -l
```

and comparing to the permissions displayed in the web interface of our Gitlab GUI. To get the GUI to also recognize the fact that I do not care about permission changes on Windows, I ran the command

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

which tells git to universally ignore permission changes in all of my projects. After running that `git config` command, the GUI does not complain anymore.